# Answers/questions profile page improvements

Tags: feature-request

I've answered a few questions on SU over time, but am curious how many of them were correct (marked as answer). If we could have a ratio (for all time), that would be great.

The same can apply to questions too (which could be a gentle reminder that people are not marking as answer). So when I got to my question page, I can see a ratio or percentage ("You've answered/marked 60% of questions/answers")

So, in the profile pages we all have there is a section for answer and questions. Can we add some summary data, like ratio (or anything else which could be useful)

Comment: Actually, the site already can do user-specific searches. And it actually fills in your userid in the search box when you're on your profile page.

Comment: Hmm. The ratio could be pretty trivially implemented as an API app. Or a Data Explorer query.

Comment: I feel a little foolish about that... Thanks @Bob, that will save time. Do you think I should amend the question to only focus on the ratio bit then?

Answer (score 3):

Yay, Data Explorer!

- [Answer ratio](http://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/query/218993/answers-marked-as-answer)
- [Question ratio](http://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/query/218997/questions-with-marked-answer)

May be about a week out of date.

Comment: I tried this, and whilst it's not in the ideal place, it also proves I really suck at answer questions!! :)

Comment: Well, the argument against more data on the user profile page has always been clutter. In the event that not enough people really want that information, this is a viable alternative.

Comment: And I guess I'd need to open a new post to have a custom dashboard :) ?